# Rendering word document through shiny app, odd behaviour

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, render, pandoc

I can't make the production of my word report use my template. The report gets generated but not with my styling.
I saw similar threads [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1451) and [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/issues-generating-downloadable-reports-from-shiny-server-word-document/14655) but nothing i saw there resolved my issues.

The second problem i have (see example below) is that no matter which country is selected, the report always takes the name of the first country in the list (while it shouldn't be the case, the name should respond to the country input).

```
    library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  'Please select a country from the list below: ',
    selectInput(
      'Country',
      'Country',
      c('Albania','Belgium','Romania'),
      selected = NULL,
      multiple = FALSE,
      selectize = TRUE,
      width = NULL,
      size = NULL
    ),
  downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
)



server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  ##### Report generation #####
  
  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
    filename = paste0(input$Country,'_',Sys.Date(),".docx"),
    content = function(file) {
      # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
      # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
      # can happen when deployed).
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      
      # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
      params <- list(Country = input$Country)
      
      # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
      # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
      # from the code in this app).
      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    }
  )
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And the report.Rmd

```
---
title: "Title"
output: word_document
reference_docx: Template.docx
params:
  Country: NA,
 
  
---

# `r params$Country` 

`r Sys.Date()`
```

Comment: Maybe simply an issue with your YAML. See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/word-document.html#word-document on how correctly specify and indent the YAML options.

Comment: You are compiling the Rmd in `tempdir()`, shoudn't you have to copy `Template.docx` to this directory as well?

Comment: Mm my Template.docx is in the same folder as my app.R and my report.Rmd. Should it go somewhere else?